# Using "forever" with NPM script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, forever

I have a simple NPM build script which is run using "npm run build". It will listen for file changes, then transpile using babel

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel -w js_uncompiled --out-dir js --source-maps"
  }
```

This issue i'm having is regular crashes probably due to having not the best network (We work off the server). I've considered using "forever" to restart the node server once it crashes but i've had no luck with it using the following script

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 babel -w js_uncompiled --out-dir js --source-maps"
  }
```

The error I get is

```
A:\PortalTom>npm run build


> babeltest@1.0.0 build A:\PortalTom
> forever --minUptime 10000 --spinSleepTime 10000 babel -w js_uncompiled --out-dir js --source-maps

error:   Cannot start forever
error:   script A:\PortalTom\babel does not exist.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

e/

Here's my current package.json : pastebin.com/iRUpAxLm, It all works perfectly (exscuse the many babel modules had to do some hacky stuff to get rid of strict mode to not flag all our old codebase)

I've tried installing forever globally also using "npm install forever -g"

Comment: Interesting choice of driver letter, reminds me of floppy drive horrors.. This isn't on a floppy drive is it ?

Comment: do you have babel in package.json?

Comment: Make sure you have forever install global `npm install -g forever`

Comment: @Pogrindis my manager said the same thing :D, I like having my dev drive @ the top of my mapped drive list, No need to worry about floppies anymore luckily!

Heres my package.json
http://pastebin.com/iRUpAxLm

Has no problems running babel like that, However forever doesn't work.